# How to instantiate an object in a .drl file

Tags: java, instantiation, drools

I am totally new with this drools staff. Thus I am having a little bit of trouble here.

```
rule "Raise the alarm when we have one or more fires"
    when
exists Fire()
then 
    insert( new Alarm() );  
end
```

when I have this code it works fine. But I want to change this a bit like :

```
rule "Raise the alarm when we have one or more fires"
    when
exists Fire()
then 
    $alarm = new Alarm();
    $alarm.RingBell();
    insert( $alarm );  
end
```

probably you understood what I am trying to do here. I want to instantiate the Alarm class and fire the RingBell method of it. But it gives me this error

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Raise the alarm when we have one or more fires']
    com/sample/Rule_Raise_the_alarm_when_we_have_one_or_more_fires_cd7449c70a6a48c78f4e291495d23b05.java (8:436) : alarm cannot be resolved

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.readKnowledgeBase(DroolsTest.java:117)
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:28)
```

If you guys help me out here I would appreciate it :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because $alarm variable is never declared. Try to do the following:

```
rule "Raise the alarm when we have one or more fires"
    when
exists Fire()
then 
    Alarm $alarm = new Alarm();
    $alarm.RingBell();
    insert( $alarm );  
end
```

The important line is: ***Alarm*** $alarm = new Alarm();